# rails db structure wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a view V1 that was created in a migration at one point. And recently we've created a second view V2 used by V1 (sub query).

The problem is that our db/structure.sql seems to be generated the wrong way/order, because when I want to run db:structure:load ( or  rake db:test:prepare). It says the following error:

> Mysql2::Error: Table 'V2' doesn't exist CREATE VIEW 'V1'...

and if I look at the db/structure.sql, I can see first:

```
CREATE VIEW 'V1' ...

CREATE VIEW 'V2' ...
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Thank you!